# How to set up the 1Password SSH agent for Gitkraken?

Tags: ssh, 1password

Although Gitkraken is compatible with 1Password, this is not working out of the box even with `Use local SSH agent` option checked in **Preferences**.

https://developer.1password.com/docs/ssh/agent/compatibility/#gitkraken

[image: configured ssh is invalid]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Prepend the following line to desktop entry of Gitkraken and replace the USER:

```
Exec=env SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/home/USER/.1password/agent.sock
```

---

To fix this (**fix is required after each upgrade of Gitkraken**) you edit desktop entries with correct env variable.

Make sure your entry path matches one used for your distribution in this case Ubuntu.

`vim /usr/share/applications/gitkraken-url-handler.desktop`

```
# /usr/share/applications/gitkraken-url-handler.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Name=GitKraken
Comment=Unleash your repo
GenericName=Git Client
Exec=/usr/bin/gitkraken --uri=%U
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/gitkraken.png
Type=Application
NoDisplay=true
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Development;RevisionControl;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/gitkraken;
StartupWMClass=gitkraken
```

And extend the line with `Exec` to:

```
Exec=env SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/home/USER/.1password/agent.sock /usr/bin/gitkraken --uri=%U
```

You should also do the same for this entry as well:

```
#/usr/share/applications/gitkraken.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Name=GitKraken
Comment=Unleash your repo
GenericName=Git Client
Exec=/usr/share/gitkraken/gitkraken %U
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/gitkraken.png
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Development;RevisionControl;
MimeType=text/plain;
StartupWMClass=gitkraken
```

Modified line:

```
Exec=env SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/home/USER/.1password/agent.sock /usr/share/gitkraken/gitkraken %U
```

Make sure to replace USER with actual USER wise step would be to have those in your home directory as desktop entries.

Answer (score 1):

if you're using KDE Plasma, you can add a file to your `~/.config/plasma-workspace/env/` folder (I called mine `sshsock.sh`) with the following:

```bash
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$HOME/.1password/agent.sock
```

after a restart that variable will be available to gitkraken and it should work.

if you're not using kde, you may be able to get a similar result by adding the above to your `~/.xsession` or `~/.profile`